# TravisCI with npm run test from create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, travis-ci, create-react-app

I am trying to perform automated testing with `TravisCI` with my project generated by create react app.

I was told that `npm run test -- --coverage` should stop the `watch mode` or the prompt from showing up when running `npm run test`. However I am still seeing the prompt.

```
Watch Usage
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press o to only run tests related to changed files.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

Updates:

Project structure

```
/redribbon
  .travis.yml
  docker-compose.yml
  /client
    package.json
    Dockerfile
    Dockerfile.dev
  /server
```

I've learned by default TravisCI will have `CI=true` set automatically. Currently, my `npm run test` in `[package.json][1]` has not been touched.

`.travis.yml`

```
sudo: required    
services:
  - docker
before_install:
  - docker build -t bradford/redribbon-client -f ./client/Dockerfile.dev ./client
script:
  - docker run bradford/redribbon-client npm run test
```

TravisCI output can be seen [here](https://travis-ci.org/liondancer/redribbon/builds/528117890)

Without TravisCI, when I run the command `npm run test` or `npm test` this is my output:

```
No tests found related to files changed since last commit.
Press `a` to run all tests, or run Jest with `--watchAll`.

Watch Usage
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

If I added `CI=true` --> `"test": "CI=true react-scripts test",`

This is my output:

```
$ npm test

> client@0.1.0 test /Users/bli1/Development/projects/sideprojects/redribbon/client
> CI=true react-scripts test

No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In /Users/bli1/Development/projects/sideprojects/redribbon/client
  14 files checked.
  testMatch: /Users/bli1/Development/projects/sideprojects/redribbon/client/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}, /Users/bli1/Development/projects/sideprojects/redribbon/client/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx} - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 14 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Comment: *"I was told"* - where? `--coverage` *adds* the coverage reporting, but the `test` script still watches by default. The easiest way to run without watching is to set the env var `CI=true`, which should [already be done](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables) in Travis.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can't it ti work anymore. I am following a video tutorial and it works for him. Right now I have `"test": "CI=true react-scripts test"` https://travis-ci.org/liondancer/redribbon/builds/528116919

Comment: That exact script works fine for me on a basic CRA app. Are you on Windows (that will affect how you set env vars)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe nope, I am on OSX

Comment: @jonrsharpe you can follow along =D https://github.com/liondancer/redribbon/blob/master/client/package.json#L16 https://travis-ci.org/liondancer/redribbon/builds/528117890

Comment: Same here, macOS. You'll have to give more information *in the question*, then, as I'm seeing the expected behaviour on this machine (and I've used the same `CI=true` trick multiple times before).

Comment: @jonrsharpe added some more information. Please let me know what else would be helpful. Ill think of other information to add as well

Comment: That says `No tests found, exiting with code 1`, not `Watch usage...`. Are you sure you're asking about the right problem? *Do* you have tests to discover?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am trying to stop watch mode or the prompt from displaying because that would cause my TravisCI build to pass or else my build will not complete. I don't care about the actual tests. Me being as tired as I am, I did not notice the obvious argument `--passwithNoTests`. That got what I wanted. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

Try this instead in your travis.yml,

```
sudo: required    
services:
  - docker
before_install:
  - docker build -t bradford/redribbon-client -f ./client/Dockerfile.dev ./client
script:
  - docker run -e CI=true bradford/redribbon-client npm run test
```

This will allow you to run the test and exit from the image once the tests are completed

Answer (score 1):

Please use the `watchAll=false` flag when running tests from create-react-app inside a docker container.

In .travis.yml:

```
script: docker run <image_name> npm run test -- --watchAll=false
```

Comment: Please give your code a format of code to better be able to read it.